# Permissions that can only be set for privilegged apps

Tags: android, android-permissions, privileges

Looking for some info source to know, what kind of permissions that can only be granted to privileged app. Following [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of permissions only granted to system apps:

```
    [[311, android.intent.category.MASTER_CLEAR.permission.C2D_MESSAGE ],
 [48 , android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM                  ],
 [85 , android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES                ],
 [164, android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY      ],
 [380, android.permission.ACCESS_DRM_CERTIFICATES                  ],
 [528, android.permission.ACCESS_EPHEMERAL_APPS                    ],
 [129, android.permission.ACCESS_FM_RADIO                          ],
 [529, android.permission.ACCESS_INPUT_FLINGER                     ],
 [313, android.permission.ACCESS_KEYGUARD_SECURE_STORAGE           ],
 [94 , android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION                     ],
 [353, android.permission.ACCESS_MTP                               ],
 [373, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_CONDITIONS                ],
 [452, android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS                     ],
 [416, android.permission.ACCESS_PDB_STATE                         ],
 [210, android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER                   ],
 [388, android.permission.ACCESS_VOICE_INTERACTION_SERVICE         ],
 [504, android.permission.ACCESS_VR_MANAGER                        ],
 [257, android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER                          ],
 [489, android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK             ],
 [298, android.permission.ASEC_ACCESS                              ],
 [306, android.permission.ASEC_CREATE                              ],
 [367, android.permission.ASEC_DESTROY                             ],
 [420, android.permission.ASEC_MOUNT_UNMOUNT                       ],
 [370, android.permission.ASEC_RENAME                              ],
 [356, android.permission.BACKUP                                   ],
 [265, android.permission.BATTERY_STATS                            ],
 [458, android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE               ],
 [262, android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET                           ],
 [333, android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_MESSAGING_SERVICE           ],
 [110, android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES                    ],
 [525, android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE              ],
 [350, android.permission.BIND_CONDITION_PROVIDER_SERVICE          ],
 [246, android.permission.BIND_CONNECTION_SERVICE                  ],
 [83 , android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN                        ],
 [390, android.permission.BIND_DIRECTORY_SEARCH                    ],
 [101, android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE                       ],
 [53 , android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE                      ],
 [463, android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD                        ],
 [152, android.permission.BIND_INTENT_FILTER_VERIFIER              ],
 [315, android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE                         ],
 [81 , android.permission.BIND_KEYGUARD_APPWIDGET                  ],
 [280, android.permission.BIND_MIDI_DEVICE_SERVICE                 ],
 [482, android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE                         ],
 [275, android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE       ],
 [304, android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_RANKER_SERVICE         ],
 [325, android.permission.BIND_PACKAGE_VERIFIER                    ],
 [76 , android.permission.BIND_PRINT_RECOMMENDATION_SERVICE        ],
 [88 , android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE                       ],
 [389, android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SPOOLER_SERVICE               ],
 [134, android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE                 ],
 [418, android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS                         ],
 [299, android.permission.BIND_REMOTE_DISPLAY                      ],
 [329, android.permission.BIND_ROUTE_PROVIDER                      ],
 [91 , android.permission.BIND_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_PRESENTER_SERVICE],
 [277, android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE                   ],
 [160, android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE          ],
 [508, android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE                        ],
 [413, android.permission.BIND_TRUST_AGENT                         ],
 [135, android.permission.BIND_TV_INPUT                            ],
 [343, android.permission.BIND_TV_REMOTE_SERVICE                   ],
 [190, android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION                   ],
 [255, android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE                         ],
 [96 , android.permission.BIND_VR_LISTENER_SERVICE                 ],
 [141, android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER                           ],
 [233, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_MAP                            ],
 [300, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED                     ],
 [230, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_STACK                          ],
 [73 , android.permission.BRICK                                    ],
 [209, android.permission.BROADCAST_NETWORK_PRIVILEGED             ],
 [444, android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED                ],
 [150, android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS                            ],
 [192, android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH                       ],
 [387, android.permission.CACHE_CONTENT                            ],
 [151, android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED                          ],
 [500, android.permission.CAMERA_DISABLE_TRANSMIT_LED              ],
 [143, android.permission.CAMERA_SEND_SYSTEM_EVENTS                ],
 [199, android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD                    ],
 [279, android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT                     ],
 [317, android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT              ],
 [157, android.permission.CAPTURE_TV_INPUT                         ],
 [451, android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT                     ],
 [242, android.permission.CARRIER_FILTER_SMS                       ],
 [409, android.permission.CHANGE_APP_IDLE_STATE                    ],
 [423, android.permission.CHANGE_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING           ],
 [132, android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE           ],
 [358, android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION                     ],
 [465, android.permission.CHANGE_DEVICE_IDLE_TEMP_WHITELIST        ],
 [408, android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE                          ],
 [254, android.permission.CLEAR_APP_GRANTED_URI_PERMISSIONS        ],
 [119, android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA                      ],
 [352, android.permission.CONFIGURE_DISPLAY_COLOR_TRANSFORM        ],
 [59 , android.permission.CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY                   ],
 [316, android.permission.CONFIRM_FULL_BACKUP                      ],
 [431, android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL                    ],
 [502, android.permission.CONTROL_INCALL_EXPERIENCE                ],
 [57 , android.permission.CONTROL_KEYGUARD                         ],
 [115, android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES                 ],
 [228, android.permission.CONTROL_VPN                              ],
 [108, android.permission.CONTROL_WIFI_DISPLAY                     ],
 [364, android.permission.COPY_PROTECTED_DATA                      ],
 [479, android.permission.CREATE_USERS                             ],
 [481, android.permission.CRYPT_KEEPER                             ],
 [345, android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES                       ],
 [537, android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES                          ],
 [175, android.permission.DEVICE_POWER                             ],
 [290, android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC                               ],
 [401, android.permission.DISPATCH_NFC_MESSAGE                     ],
 [488, android.permission.DISPATCH_PROVISIONING_MESSAGE            ],
 [514, android.permission.DUMP                                     ],
 [195, android.permission.DVB_DEVICE                               ],
 [433, android.permission.FACTORY_TEST                             ],
 [469, android.permission.FILTER_EVENTS                            ],
 [495, android.permission.FORCE_BACK                               ],
 [449, android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES                      ],
 [71 , android.permission.FRAME_STATS                              ],
 [396, android.permission.FREEZE_SCREEN                            ],
 [270, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED                  ],
 [515, android.permission.GET_APP_GRANTED_URI_PERMISSIONS          ],
 [97 , android.permission.GET_APP_OPS_STATS                        ],
 [486, android.permission.GET_DETAILED_TASKS                       ],
 [224, android.permission.GET_INTENT_SENDER_INTENT                 ],
 [99 , android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_IMPORTANCE                   ],
 [332, android.permission.GET_PASSWORD                             ],
 [149, android.permission.GET_PROCESS_STATE_AND_OOM_SCORE          ],
 [117, android.permission.GET_TOP_ACTIVITY_INFO                    ],
 [427, android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH                            ],
 [170, android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH_CONTROL                    ],
 [421, android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS                ],
 [303, android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST                            ],
 [462, android.permission.HDMI_CEC                                 ],
 [522, android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS                            ],
 [247, android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS        ],
 [104, android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER                ],
 [124, android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES                         ],
 [52 , android.permission.INTENT_FILTER_VERIFICATION_AGENT         ],
 [368, android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS                    ],
 [261, android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL               ],
 [138, android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW                   ],
 [464, android.permission.INVOKE_CARRIER_SETUP                     ],
 [86 , android.permission.KILL_UID                                 ],
 [250, android.permission.LAUNCH_TRUST_AGENT_SETTINGS              ],
 [360, android.permission.LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS                        ],
 [517, android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE                        ],
 [169, android.permission.LOOP_RADIO                               ],
 [460, android.permission.MANAGE_ACTIVITY_STACKS                   ],
 [384, android.permission.MANAGE_APP_OPS_RESTRICTIONS              ],
 [155, android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS                        ],
 [450, android.permission.MANAGE_CA_CERTIFICATES                   ],
 [407, android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS                     ],
 [415, android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS                         ],
 [237, android.permission.MANAGE_FINGERPRINT                       ],
 [435, android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA_PROJECTION                  ],
 [417, android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY                    ],
 [424, android.permission.MANAGE_NOTIFICATIONS                     ],
 [186, android.permission.MANAGE_PROFILE_AND_DEVICE_OWNERS         ],
 [125, android.permission.MANAGE_SOUND_TRIGGER                     ],
 [258, android.permission.MANAGE_USB                               ],
 [339, android.permission.MANAGE_USERS                             ],
 [130, android.permission.MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES                  ],
 [158, android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR                             ],
 [536, android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL                    ],
 [490, android.permission.MODIFY_APPWIDGET_BIND_PERMISSIONS        ],
 [92 , android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_ROUTING                     ],
 [327, android.permission.MODIFY_CELL_BROADCASTS                   ],
 [328, android.permission.MODIFY_DAY_NIGHT_MODE                    ],
 [480, android.permission.MODIFY_NETWORK_ACCOUNTING                ],
 [137, android.permission.MODIFY_PARENTAL_CONTROLS                 ],
 [503, android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE                       ],
 [404, android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS                 ],
 [269, android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS                ],
 [281, android.permission.MOVE_PACKAGE                             ],
 [240, android.permission.NET_ADMIN                                ],
 [429, android.permission.NET_TUNNELING                            ],
 [288, android.permission.NFC_HANDOVER_STATUS                      ],
 [487, android.permission.NOTIFY_PENDING_SYSTEM_UPDATE             ],
 [530, android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS         ],
 [405, android.permission.OEM_UNLOCK_STATE                         ],
 [447, android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG                     ],
 [267, android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS                      ],
 [335, android.permission.PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT               ],
 [506, android.permission.PACKET_KEEPALIVE_OFFLOAD                 ],
 [174, android.permission.PEERS_MAC_ADDRESS                        ],
 [244, android.permission.PERFORM_CDMA_PROVISIONING                ],
 [197, android.permission.PERFORM_SIM_ACTIVATION                   ],
 [121, android.permission.PROVIDE_TRUST_AGENT                      ],
 [375, android.permission.QUERY_DO_NOT_ASK_CREDENTIALS_ON_BOOT     ],
 [283, android.permission.READ_BLOCKED_NUMBERS                     ],
 [374, android.permission.READ_DREAM_STATE                         ],
 [511, android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER                        ],
 [385, android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE                         ],
 [362, android.permission.READ_LOGS                                ],
 [379, android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY               ],
 [531, android.permission.READ_OEM_UNLOCK_STATE                    ],
 [234, android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE                 ],
 [293, android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE              ],
 [285, android.permission.READ_SEARCH_INDEXABLES                   ],
 [100, android.permission.READ_WIFI_CREDENTIAL                     ],
 [44 , android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS                           ],
 [400, android.permission.REBOOT                                   ],
 [93 , android.permission.RECEIVE_BLUETOOTH_MAP                    ],
 [98 , android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE             ],
 [471, android.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST              ],
 [264, android.permission.RECEIVE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_USAGE             ],
 [331, android.permission.RECEIVE_STK_COMMANDS                     ],
 [292, android.permission.RECEIVE_WIFI_CREDENTIAL_CHANGE           ],
 [63 , android.permission.RECOVERY                                 ],
 [251, android.permission.REGISTER_CALL_PROVIDER                   ],
 [406, android.permission.REGISTER_CONNECTION_MANAGER              ],
 [393, android.permission.REGISTER_SIM_SUBSCRIPTION                ],
 [51 , android.permission.REGISTER_WINDOW_MANAGER_LISTENERS        ],
 [49 , android.permission.REMOTE_AUDIO_PLAYBACK                    ],
 [466, android.permission.REMOVE_DRM_CERTIFICATES                  ],
 [182, android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS                             ],
 [166, android.permission.RESET_FINGERPRINT_LOCKOUT                ],
 [165, android.permission.RESET_SHORTCUT_MANAGER_THROTTLING        ],
 [219, android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT                  ],
 [140, android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_TOKEN                    ],
 [338, android.permission.REVOKE_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS               ],
 [289, android.permission.SCORE_NETWORKS                           ],
 [126, android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE                 ],
 [512, android.permission.SEND_SMS_NO_CONFIRMATION                 ],
 [274, android.permission.SERIAL_PORT                              ],
 [282, android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER                     ],
 [302, android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH                        ],
 [205, android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE                      ],
 [163, android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP                            ],
 [62 , android.permission.SET_INPUT_CALIBRATION                    ],
 [371, android.permission.SET_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT                      ],
 [337, android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION                          ],
 [422, android.permission.SET_POINTER_SPEED                        ],
 [342, android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS               ],
 [66 , android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT                        ],
 [534, android.permission.SET_SCREEN_COMPATIBILITY                 ],
 [319, android.permission.SET_TIME                                 ],
 [181, android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE                            ],
 [347, android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT                  ],
 [131, android.permission.SHUTDOWN                                 ],
 [87 , android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES              ],
 [142, android.permission.START_ANY_ACTIVITY                       ],
 [113, android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS                 ],
 [510, android.permission.STATUS_BAR                               ],
 [284, android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE                       ],
 [263, android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES                        ],
 [78 , android.permission.STORAGE_INTERNAL                         ],
 [310, android.permission.SUBSTITUTE_NOTIFICATION_APP_NAME         ],
 [80 , android.permission.TABLET_MODE                              ],
 [64 , android.permission.TEMPORARY_ENABLE_ACCESSIBILITY           ],
 [271, android.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED                        ],
 [256, android.permission.TRUST_LISTENER                           ],
 [215, android.permission.TV_INPUT_HARDWARE                        ],
 [383, android.permission.TV_VIRTUAL_REMOTE_CONTROLLER             ],
 [526, android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS                     ],
 [372, android.permission.UPDATE_CONFIG                            ],
 [229, android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS                      ],
 [378, android.permission.UPDATE_LOCK                              ],
 [294, android.permission.UPDATE_LOCK_TASK_PACKAGES                ],
 [359, android.permission.USER_ACTIVITY                            ],
 [320, android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS                       ],
 [202, android.permission.WRITE_BLOCKED_NUMBERS                    ],
 [395, android.permission.WRITE_DREAM_STATE                        ],
 [102, android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES                          ],
 [200, android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE                      ],
 [272, android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS                    ],
 [55 , android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS                           ],
 [201, com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL             ],
 [484, com.android.voicemail.permission.WRITE_VOICEMAIL            ]]
```

Comment: can you please provide the source for that list?

Comment: unfortunately, it was in my notes